# understanding code generated by Java hotspot JIT for float test

Tags: java, assembly, jit, disassembly, jvm-hotspot

I have noticed that some innocent looking if-statements in one of my number crunching programs significantly slow down the execution (JRE 1.8.25, 64-bit Hotspot build 25.25-b02, Intel 64-bit CPU).

I have checked the code generated by the JIT compiler and it looks a little bit strange. Here is a simple function to illustrate the problem:

```
private float test(float a,float b) {
    float c=a+b;
    if(c<0) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the interesting part of the generated code:

```
...
0x2bd17ae: vaddss  xmm0,xmm0,xmm1
0x2bd17b2: vxorps  xmm1,xmm1,xmm1
0x2bd17b6: vucomiss xmm0,xmm1
0x2bd17ba: mov     esi,1h
0x2bd17bf: jp      2bd17d8h
0x2bd17c5: jnbe    2bd17d8h
0x2bd17cb: mov     esi,0h
0x2bd17d0: je      2bd17d8h
0x2bd17d6: dec     esi               ;*fcmpg
0x2bd17d8: cmp     esi,0h
0x2bd17db: mov     rsi,57448760h     ; {metadata(method data for {method} ...}
0x2bd17e5: mov     rdi,108h
0x2bd17ef: jnl     2bd17ffh
0x2bd17f5: mov     rdi,118h
0x2bd17ff: mov     rbx,qword ptr [rsi+rdi]
0x2bd1803: lea     rbx,[rbx+1h]
0x2bd1807: mov     qword ptr [rsi+rdi],rbx
0x2bd180b: jnl     2bd1c1fh          ;*ifge
...
// straightforward code for "return -1f" and "return 0f" follows
...
```

The code from 0x2bd17ba to 0x2bd1807 doesn't make much sense to me. Why is it there? Any idea what it does?

Edit: Thinking about it, it might be some code added by the JIT compiler to collect runtime statistics (just guessing because of the 'metadata' comment). But the question is: why is there? I have called the method several million times, so I would assume that the code should have reached its final optimized form.

Answer (score 3):

`(v)ucomiss` sets the flags as follows:

```
unordered    zf,pf,cf = 111
greater      zf,pf,cf = 000
less than    zf,pf,cf = 001
equal        zf,pf,cf = 100
```

So this code:

```
    mov     esi,1h
    jp      label  ; if unordered, or
    jnbe    label  ; if greater than, keep it at 1
    mov     esi,0h
    je      label  ; if equal, make 0
    dec     esi    ; otherwise -1
label:
```

Makes `esi = 1` (if unordered or greater), `esi = 0` (if equal), `esi = -1` (if smaller)

Then it compared `esi` to 0 and the line marked "ifge" does indeed check for "if greater or equal" (sort of, also includes the unordered case) by checking that `esi` is not less than 0, so the "else" part of the branch.

The part from 0x2bd17db to 0x2bd1807 increments two counters conditionally, either one or the other, depending on which way the branch takes. So it's some sort of profiling. Perhaps used for optimization later, but I don't know (what else would you use it for though).

They could just have done:

```
vaddss  xmm0,xmm0,xmm1
vxorps  xmm1,xmm1,xmm1
vcmpss  xmm0,xmm1,1
vandps  xmm0,xmm0,[rel negative_one]
ret
```

With no profiling, but then there would be no branch so nothing to profile.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the esi flag. I already speculated about some connection to optimization or profiling before I saw your answer (see edit). But I am still wondering while the counters are still there after having called the function more than 10 million times. Shouldn't that stuff be eventually removed? It is really much slower than expected.

Comment: @RmS I hope it goes away eventually, profiling sort of misses the point if it's just perpetually slowing you down. I don't know such details about HotSpot though. Maybe try even more iterations?

Comment: Called 200 million times, still there (even in the inlined version at the caller). I am wondering whether this is a HotSpot bug or just an artifact of the debug output. The runtime measurements (significant slow down) indicate the former.

Comment: I see what you mean and it indeed looks a bit unoptimized on the part of HotSpot.